# Getting all backbone angles in Pymol (psi, phi, omega)

Tags: pymol

I've only been using pymol for a few weeks and would like to display all backbone angles (phi, psi and omega of a peptide) as a list for comparison. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks for your help

BG

i tried command phi_psi Dataname

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74328705/pymol-scripting-how-does-interate-work-how-to-make-a-csv-from-the-interate-ou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting all dihedral angles in Pymol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355401/getting-all-dihedral-angles-in-pymol)